# google apps script getFolder(path)

Tags: google-apps-script

since some days a script doesn't run which runs well before.
getFolder(path) doesn't work.
path is "top_folder_in_drive/next_level_folder" . The rootfolder is not part of this path-string.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details - some code, perhaps ? 
Try wrapping your code in a try-catch block and see what is the exception. That will answer your question in most cases. 
If you still believe nothing has changed and you are still having problems, open an issue in the issue tracker